# Asus Rog Strix Scar 17 No Sound

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I got a new Asus Rog Strix Scar 17. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 after installation everything was worked great I just accepted an update and I lost PC sound before the update I could use all functionality of volume control and can be heard what plays.

I followed several instructions about solving this issue

https://leimao.github.io/blog/Ubuntu-No-Sound-Fix/

https://medium.com/@win10tricks/how-to-fix-the-no-sound-issue-in-ubuntu-18-04-220ba9bbe61e

nothing works to solve it.

in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file if i change

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook
```

speakers work but I can't control volume level it only works %100 or %0 level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem same laptop same day. Are you me?

I just found the solution. Insert this in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc294-lenovo-mic
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hahaha really interesting :) thank you. it works

Comment: Does both the headphone jack and the speaker work using this configuration?

Comment: I had the same problem, exactly in this file I added this line `options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook` and It's works

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue could potentially be related to unassigned pins inside the audio controller. This was the case for my Asus Strix Scar 17 G733Q dual booting Ubuntu 21.10, Linux kernel 5.15.

This fix applies to the following issues:

- Headset combo-jack - microphone does not work.
- Internal speakers - no high frequencies, as if only sub-woofer works (Sound comes out like its very muffled)

**Fix**
You need to kill pulseaudio to apply changes. Execute `pulseaudio -k` multiple times quickly until you start to get error.  Once was not enough for me as pulseaudio is restarted by system, but it gives up after killing it for 5 times in a row or so.

The fix comes by overriding pins using hdajackretask from alsa-tools
`sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui`
Set the following Pin ID's: to the following values

```
0x14 - Internal Speaker (back)  
0x19 - Microphone  
0x1e - Internal Speaker (LFE)
```

(screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/33zpB.jpg).
It should look something like this
[image: hdajackretask override]

Also you may need to select correct profile for sound card.
It is either "Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input" (4.1 also works, sounds slightly different, select the one you like better) in pavucontrol, or same can be in Desktop Environment's sound settings, at least it can be set in Gnome Sound Settings.

If this fixed the audio/mic issue:
In the `hdajackretask` UI you can click `install boot override` and restart, which will apply the pin assignments to survive past reboots, otherwise the fix only works only until reboot.

For some reason the Test button in sound settings ignores part of the speakers, so test your changes manually using audio or video clip with audible low and high frequencies.

I originally found this information in a reddit thread
https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/mfokva/asus_strix_scar_17_g733qs_and_linux/
The credit for this fix should go entirely to https://www.reddit.com/user/horkid/

Edit: Added information in case link goes down.

Comment: This might help today but what about later when this link no longer works? If it has information that could be the answer it needs to be in this answer not just a link.

Comment: @David you're right, link rot is real. Ive edited my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ive tried the alc294-lenovo-mic method and at a first glance it works great. But the sound "leaks" through the microjack.

For controlling the volume, in addition to adding options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf you have to:

1-Edit the file /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common

2-Add the following lines before the [Element PCM] block:

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

3-Restart computer